# Haskell: Assigning a value to a String

Tags: haskell

My task consists in imitating features of an imperative programming language in Haskell. Now I'm struggling with assigning a value to a string. The point is that I have to do it with the types Env and Sigma. Env assigns a String (variable name) to a Location Loc. Sigma assigns the Location to a specific value. Here's the code:

```
type Loc = Int                 --Loc for Location
type Env =  String -> Loc 
type Sigma = Loc -> Int

assign :: String -> Int -> Env -> Sigma -> Sigma
assign name value env sig = \input -> ??
```

Now I don't know how to do it in the function `assign` of my program. The function should store the String name and the Location loc in the function env and also store the same location loc and the Value val in the function sig which must be returned by the whole function 'assign'.

Testing it with e.g. `env = \"test"->42`, `sig= \42->6` (sig and env just provisionally for test case),`assign "x" 45 env sig` and then `sig (env "x")` should return 45. I don't know how you manage it to do without assigning the Locations to env and sig. Can you help me and tell me what I should do?

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `sig`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What do you mean with implementation? sig is just the parameter of type Sigma for the function

Comment: Then what do you mean by _“then `sig (env "x")` should return 45”_?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Oh right. This is just for the test case. Corrected it in my question

Comment: Your test case is wrong. In addition, either your `assign` type signature or the `env` function in your test case is wrong. If the type signature is correct, your test case might look like `let { env x = case x of { "test" -> 42; "x" -> 43 }; sig = \42 -> 6 } in let { sig2 = assign "x" 45 env sig } in sig2 (env "x")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

you need to start by comparing the `input` location to the location of `name`, i.e. `env name`.

When these are equal, you know the new value to return.

When these locations differ, you can access the old `Sigma` to retrieve the old value for the `input` location.

Comment: if you mean this: `assign name value env sig = \inp -> (if (inp == (env s)) then val else (sig inp))` . I tried this also but I wonder if this is correct. I mean the String name must be already assigned to the specific Location in env to use this function properly.

Comment: @JohnDoe Looks good to me (apart from s being name). Yes, this requires `name` to be already assigned a location by `env`, but there's no way around that. Usually you have a "declare" function which provides you with a new `env`, allocating a new location for the new variable. But this function is meant to assign to an already defined variable.

Comment: Yeah s was just the parameter I used for the String. I thought about it again and put into the context of my task this should be the correct solution. So thanks a lot for your help :)